# Resultados estranhos ao calcular o fatorial

Tags: java, fatorial

Não consigo encontrar qual o erro no meu código. Quando coloco números menores ou iguais a 12 meu programa da o resultado certo, porém a partir do numero 13 os valores saem equivocados e não consigo saber por que. Qual o erro?

```
class vdois {

    static int fatorial (int numero){
        int fat = 1;
        while (numero >0) {

            fat *= numero;
            numero--;
        }

        return fat;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero = 13;
        System.out.println(numero+"! = "+fatorial(numero));
    }

}
```

Comment: Não é o mesmo pois quero saber qual o erro na maneira que eu fiz.

Comment: Não está excendendo o valor máximo do `int`? Substitui por `float` para você ver.

Comment: Deu certo! Mas ao inves de printar  62272... printou 6.2272..., tem problema acontecer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque o valor do tipo `int` é no máximo 2.147.483.647. Se você calcular o fatorial de 13, verá que vale 6.227.020.800, ou seja, já é impossível representar o valor com uma variável `int`. Você pode corrigir isso alterando o tipo para `double`:

```
class vdois {

    static double fatorial (int numero){
        double fat = 1;
        while (numero >0) {

            fat *= numero;
            numero--;
        }

        return fat;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero = 13;
        System.out.println(numero+"! = "+fatorial(numero));
    }

}
```

Com isso, você já aumenta o range de valores possíveis na entrada, pois o valor máximo do tipo `double` é 1.7976931348623157E308 e, se fiz os testes certos, é possível calcular o fatorial de até 171.